# Default TEncoding.UTF8 discarding invalid blocks of data in TStreamReader input

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe2

I'm using a TStreamReader to read data from a file that purports to be utf-8.  I have no problem reading the file until it comes to a section containing what appears to me to be a UTF-8 "£" symbol with the preceding xC2 missing - the file only contains the xA3 part of the character.  I've traced this through the run-time library until it calls

```
Result := UnicodeFromLocaleChars(FCodePage, FMBToWCharFlags,
    PAnsiChar(Bytes), ByteCount, nil, 0);
```

which returns 0 indicating that it doesn't like the input.  Unfortunately the TStreamReader simply ends up discarding this buffer of input and then continues with the rest of the file without raising an error.  This is extremely misleading about what the problem but that is just a side issue.

The issue appears to be a "defect" in the UTF-8 TEncoding class in that it simply discards the results of a failed conversion whilst the TStreamReader assumes that this isn't the behaviour of TEncoding.

I can work around this by using

```
Reader := TStreamReader.Create(FileStream, TMBCSEncoding.Create(CP_UTF8, 0, 0));
```

instead of

```
Reader := TStreamReader.Create(FileStream, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

as this makes it ignore the corrupt UTF-8 and simply include something (I haven't checked what) in my output.  However, I would like to combine allowing the data through with reporting it and there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of doing this as the behaviour is hidden deep within the library.

Does anyone know of any standard Delphi library tools for doing this or do I need to resort to a lot of custom code?

Comment: In Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) the pound sign is represented by 0xA3. Are you sure the file is UTF-8?

Comment: @LU RD Unfortunately I'm not absolutely certain what the supplier of the data has done wrong.  The header says it is UTF-8 and it is supposed to be UTF-8 but I suspect the data "area" covered doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters.  The underlying issue is that I want to detect their "errors" and report them back to them whilst still being able to process the data.

Comment: On a side note: `TStreamReader.Create(FileStream, TMBCSEncoding.Create(CP_UTF8, 0, 0));` is a memory leak on the encoding object. `TStreamReader` **does not** take ownership of the Encoding that is passed to it, so it will not `Free` it.  You have to `Free` it yourself after you are finished using the reader.

Comment: FYI, the "defect" is because `TUTF8Encoding` uses the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag when calling `MultiByteToWideChar()` (see [QC #79042](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79042)). That flag is still being used in the latest Delphi version.

Comment: FWIW, I found the performance of TStreamReader to be poor, so I wrote my own. You could do the same.

Comment: @Remy I was aware of the memory leak but was in a hurry to verify how it would work.  However, I agree that is always bad practice as such things easily get forgotten.

Comment: @David I agree with your views, stepping through the TStreamReader process to find out what was going on was pretty depressing and given the lack of rapid answer I guess that is where this is going.  At least all I really need is a readline.